# Which values of $p$, $f$ is it differentiable at the point $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Let $p \geq 1$ and $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
>
> $$f(x) =   \begin{cases}   (\sin \|x\|)^p \cos \frac{1}{\|x\|},     
>  & \quad \text{if } \|x\| \not= 0  \\ 0,  & \quad \text{if } \|x\| = 0
>  \\    \end{cases} $$
>
> **(a)** Show that $f$ is differentiable at point $x \not= (0,0)$ -  **(Done)**
>
> **(b)** Which values of $p$, $f$ is it differentiable at the point $(0,0)$?

We have seen in class that $f$ is differentiable at a point $\hat{x}$ is equivalent to find a function $f'(\hat{x}) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ such that $$\lim_{x \to \hat{x}} \frac{|f(x)-f(\hat{x})-f'(\hat{x})(x-\hat{x})|}{h}=0,$$

and we have discovered that $f'(\hat{x})(x-\hat{x}) = \nabla f(\hat{x}) \cdot (x-\hat{x})$.

So far I tried to discover the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ : $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(sin |h|)^pcos \frac{1}{|h|}}{h}$$

intuitively, I think $p$ has to be greater than $1$. We know that $(sin |h|)^pcos \frac{1}{|h|}$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

I am stucked at this point. Is anyone could help me to solve the problem? Is it a better way to find the values of $p$ for which $f$ is differentiable at the point $(0,0)$?

A related question is this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652797/show-that-f-is-differentiable-at-point-x-not-0-0-hx-sin-x).

**P.S.** Please, don't try to use a very specific analysis theory; I am only an undergraduate student (bachelor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\cos(1/\|x\|)$ approaches all values of $[-1,1]$ when $x\to0$, it is necessary and sufficient for differentiability at $0$ that $(\sin\|x\|)^p/\|x\|\to0$ when $x\to0$. But you know that $$\frac{(\sin\|x\|)^p}{\|x\|^p}\to1$$ when $x\to0$. Since
$$
\frac{(\sin\|x\|)^p}{\|x\|}=\frac{(\sin\|x\|)^p}{\|x\|^p}\|x\|^{p-1},
$$
you find readily that it converges to $0$ when $x\to0$ if and only if $p>1$.

Comment: I know that it should sufficient as argumentation, but I need a bit more. Could you develop your argumentation please?

Comment: What is not clear for you?

Comment: The link with differentiability. How can traduce that with differentiability?

Comment: I see. You know that if the derivative exists it is unique, so for $p>1$ try in your formula $f'(0)=0$ and you see from my answer that it works, while for $p=0$ the function $f$ is not even continuous at zero.